# definition of a sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, definition

The "normal" definition of a sufficient statistics is via independence of the pdf (conditional on the statistic) of the parameter $\theta$. The Fisher-Neyman theorem gives a nice characterization:

> The statistic $T$ is sufficient iff $f(x;\theta) = h(x)g(T(x);\theta)$ for two nonnegative functions $h, g$.

In the [book](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjABahUKEwj1p4rt46jIAhVJBBoKHVU7DU8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ic.unicamp.br%2F~wainer%2Fcursos%2F1s2013%2Fml%2Flivro.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGuajG_2PvDoA-EvpsjRIpc9l6W9g&sig2=stCkSyeAjNL777gHmfD9lA) All of statistics by Larry Wasserman the author defines (I quote):

> "Write $\vec{x} \iff \vec{y}$ if $f(\vec{x};\theta) = cf(\vec{y};\theta)$ for some constant $c$ that might depend on $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ but not on $\theta$. A statistic $T(\vec{x})$ is sufficient if $T(\vec{x})\iff T(\vec{y})$ implies that $\vec{x}\iff \vec{y}$

where $\vec{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ a data sample. The $T(\vec{x})\iff T(\vec{y})$ seems to be like the Fisher-Neyman thoerem with different data samples. How can one show that Wassermans definition is the same as above (or equivalent to the Fisher-Neyman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, for a random sample $\vec{X}=(X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n})$ with joint pdf $f(\vec{x}; \theta)$, a statistic $T = T(\vec{X})$ is sufficient if the conditional pdf for $\vec{X}$ given $T$ is ``$\theta$-free". This is the definition of sufficiency. I think it is easier to

(a) believe or show that the Fisher-Neyman Theorem completely characterizes a sufficient statistic

and then

(b) show that Wasserman's definition completely characterizes a sufficient statistic.

Then you will have equivalence of both characterizations.

Suppose that $T=T(\vec{X})$ is a statistic and let $t=T(\vec{x})$ be a fixed value of the statistic. By definition, $T$ is sufficient if $f_{\vec{X}|T}(\vec{x}|t;\theta)$ which is
$$
\frac{f_{\vec{X},T}(\vec{x},t;\theta)}{f_{T}(t;\theta)}
$$
does not depend on $\theta$.

Now if the argument $t$ is really $t=T(\vec{x})$, then having the joint distribution on in that numerator is redundant and unnecessary, whereas if $t \ne T(\vec{x})$, the numerator is zero.

(To sort of see this, consider the oversimplified discrete example for a random sample $X_{1}, X_{2}$ of size $2$ and the statistic $T=X_{1}+X_{2}$. Then $P(X_{1}=2, X_{2}=4, X_{1}+X_{2}=6) = P(X_{1}=2, X_{2}=4)$ and $P(X_{1}=2, X_{2}=4, X_{1}+X_{2}=22)=0$.)

If $t \ne T(\vec{x})$ and that numerator is $0$, the ratio definitely doesn't depend on $\theta$ so all is good. In the case that $t = T(\vec{x})$ we can write
$$
f_{\vec{X}|T}(\vec{x}|t;\theta) = \frac{f_{\vec{X},T}(\vec{x},t;\theta)}{f_{T}(t;\theta)} = \frac{f_{\vec{X}}(\vec{x},\theta)}{f_{T}(t;\theta)} \stackrel{notation}{=} \frac{f(\vec{x},\theta)}{f_{T}(t;\theta)}.
$$

``$\theta$-free" means that this is equal to some function that depends on $\vec{x}$ only, say
$$
\frac{f(\vec{x},\theta)}{f_{T}(t;\theta)} = h(\vec{x}).
$$
In other words,
$$
f(\vec{x};\theta) = h(\vec{x}) \, f_{T}(t;\theta) = h(\vec{x}) \, f_{T}(T(\vec{x});\theta).
$$

That was all by definition of sufficiency but you can almost see the Fisher-Neyman Theorem right there. (Certainly if this holds, we can choose the function $g$ in the F-N Theorem to be the pdf for $T$. The other direction of showing the F-N Theorem is a little bit more work.)

Now for the Wasserman definition...

If $T$ is sufficient, by definition we can write
$$
f(\vec{x};\theta) = h(\vec{x}) \, f_{T}(t;\theta) = h(\vec{x}) \, f_{T}(T(\vec{x});\theta). 
$$
If $T(\vec{x}) \Leftrightarrow T(\vec{y})$ then $f(T(\vec{x});\theta) = c \, f(T(\vec{y});\theta)$ for some constant $c$ that may depend on $\vec{x}$ and/or $\vec{y}$ but not on $\theta$. So, we have
$$
f(\vec{x};\theta) = h(\vec{x}) \, f_{T}(T(\vec{x});\theta) = h(\vec{x}) \cdot c\, f_{T}(T(\vec{y});\theta),
$$
but then $f(\vec{y};\theta) = h(\vec{y}) \, f_{T}(T(\vec{y});\theta)$ so we have that 
$$
f(\vec{x};\theta) = \underbrace{c \frac{h(\vec{x})}{h(\vec{y})}}_{\mbox{new c}} f(\vec{y};\theta)
$$
and thus $\vec{x} \Leftrightarrow \vec{y}$.

It reamins to show that, if $T(\vec{x}) \Leftrightarrow T(\vec{y})$ implies $\vec{x} \Leftrightarrow \vec{y}$, then $f(\vec{x},\theta)/f_{T}(t;\theta)$ is $\theta$-free... but I'm about to miss my last bus home for the evening!

Comment: I'd be very interested to see how, if $T(x) \Leftrightarrow T(y)$ implies $x \Leftrightarrow y$, then  $f(x, \theta)/f_T(t; \theta)$ is $\theta$-free. I'm having trouble proving this myself.

Comment: Additionally, the general statement of the Neyman-Fisher theorem says that $T$ is sufficient if $f_X(x; \theta) = \psi(T(x), \theta) h(x)$ for some functions $\psi$ and $h$. It seems to me that $\psi(t, \theta)$ need not correspond to $f_T(t; \theta)$ unless $h(x) \equiv 1$. (In general, $\psi(t, \theta)$ gives the density of $T$ with respect to the measure $H \circ T^{-1}$, where $H(dx) = h(x) dx$.) So unless I have missed something what is shown here is that, if $T$ is sufficient and $h(x) \equiv 1$, then $T(x) \Leftrightarrow T(y)$ implies $x \Leftrightarrow y$.